# How do I start my own taint infestation in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I've tried placing tainted blocks, fibrous taint, all of it. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "start" taint by placing taint blocks - you *must* change the biome type to a taint biome.

The only way to achieve this is using "[Bottled Taint](http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Bottled_Taint)"